From cartesian to (discrete) skewed coordinate system
Some context. Let's say that I have a device made of "strips" for measuring positions. By strip device I mean that I have an area $H\times W$ (see figure a) which is made of elements (the strips) telling me where the object I want to observe was traveling.
The strips are of two type and arranged like in figure b: a set of vertical strips (giving the $X$ coordinate) and set of strips tilted by a certain angle $\phi$ (giving a second coordinate). Not sure if it's relevant but it's worth specifying that the strips are numbered from $0$ to $N$ for each type and that strips with same number share the same coordinate for their centre (as in figure b).
This to me sounds simply like a skewed coordinate system, with basis $(X,U)$, like in figure c. For a given $(x_i,y_i)$ point in cartesian coordinate I want to get simply the strip number $(X_i,U_i)$ (I know there is a discretisation issue here but I guess we can forget about that, assuming to have as many strips as we want).
My idea was just follow standard change of basis
$$
\hat{X} = (1,0)\ \ \ \  \hat{U} = (\cos\phi,\sin\phi)
$$
so
$$
\begin{cases}
X = x - y \cot\phi \\ 
U = y \csc\phi
\end{cases}
$$
Get a value $(X,U)$ and discretize easily knowing the distance. This is clearly not working because for a point like the one in figure d I get $(x_0,0) \to (X_0,0)$, but $0$ is clearly not the "strip number" I want. Similar story even for a point which is not on the $x$-axis (figure e)
What is wrong in this approach?

